# base_footprint of articulated vehicle

Tags: ros2, nav2, base-footprint

I have a conceptual doubt. The base_footprint for a vehicle is given with respect to the base_link (projected on the 2D plane). I am unable to comprehend what happens when we have an articulated vehicle. How is the base_footprint then defined. Is it that we define to big polygon defined with respect to the front vehicle base_link or about the coupling point or is it two independent polygons for the two parts of the vehicle (which would make more sense considering a farming vehicle and an attached implement, but then will there be two paths and two controller),  I am unable to understand.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking is quite an interesting topic, and think there are multiple solutions.

When it comes to defining the base_footprint, I position it at ground level directly beneath the pivot point. Following a child link in the pivot point and then two childs to front and rear.

Nav2 have one reference frame when navigating, but does not mean u need two path planners or controllers. Essentially, one should design a controller capable of changing the reference frame between the front and rear based on the direction of the path(forward/reverse). At least that worked for me.

For the footprint, you'll only need 1 big polygon footprint, that uses the articulated angle feedback to dynamically change its footprint. What Marcus suggested works, but will introduce challenges in small spaces. Keep in mind that articulated vehicle such as tractors with equipment are very large, so the robot radius could results in 10-20m.

Comment: Hello Ravi, Thank you for your reply. I have seen your active interest and work in this field. Can you suggest me some documents or related works i can read and understand it better.

Comment: It really depends on specifics in your project, but google will get you really far. I am currently trying to add articulated motion support into a planner in Nav2, hopefully that will help, but will take a while before it is official.

Typically, these posts are intended to address a single issue with a corresponding answer to resolve that particular problem. Could you please mark a response as the accepted answer to avoid leaving this thread open?

Answer (score 0):

The **base_footprint** is mainly used for path planning and obstacle avoidance, it defines the robot size into the plane the trajectory planner will be drawn.

I would consider the tractor and the implement as a **single object** (covering the longest and widest points they reach when moving or turning). Then just define a polygon, circle or rectangle which cover all this area. That will be needed to create feasible paths which will **avoid that this polygon collides against projected obstacles (local costmap).**

If you decouple and use 2 different footprints, probably you would need more than one path planner+controller and I believe that is not so trivial to accomplish (and probably not dynamically correct, since the **implement is passive and will follow the tractor's trajectory).**

I've asked Dall-E to illustrate the example (the blue circle would be your robot footprint, the path planner will generate paths starting from this circle, **navigating around the obstacles' costmap boundaries).**

[image: footprint]

Comment: Thank you @Marcus. To be precise I was thinking of a vineyard when putting this question forth. There is not enough space to consider the footprint as a circle and thus has to be a polygon. But then when the vehicle makes a U turn at the end of Lane with a headland nearly 2x the length of polygon and the articulated part turning as well. If you won’t mind can you shed some insights onto this situational example.